# Threading.thread input multi args with a list not working

Tags: python, multithreading

Sorry for confusing you all, but at beginning, i tried to explain it simple but it is causing misunderstand here.

There will be some json files generated inside this path: "/opt/data/",
I'm trying to parse these json file into a list of json data after a while(time_out), if this json content a topic matching in expected list.

```
import time, Path, threading, queue

monitor_result = queue.Queue

json_path= Path("/opt/data/")
json_files = set(json_path.rglob("*.json"))
expect_topics = ["aaa", "bbb"]

def json_parse(time_out: int, topics : list, result: queue.Queue):
    while time_out > 0:
        result_list = []
        for file in json_files:
            with file.open() as f:
            temp = json.load(f)
            if temp['topic'] in topics:
                result_list.append(temp)      
         result.put(result_list)
     time.sleep(1)
     time_out -= 1

# in 5s, parsing all json files content to monitor_result
# if json file have value of key "topic" matching list expect_topics
monitor_thread = threading.Thread(
    target=json_parse,
    args=(5, expect_topics, monitor_result)
)
monitor_thread.start()
time.sleep(1)
monitor_thread.join()

json_data_list = monitor_result.get()
print(json_data_list)
```

But it looks like can't pass the list **expect_topics** into this thread as **args** input for **json_parse** function.
Is there any mistake? I have tried with **kwargs** also.

Comment: The list is working, you can test this by changing `return result` to `print(result)`.  But are you deliberately not including `monitor_threat.join()` at the end?  The program may terminate without the result as is currently written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a simple Thread object there's no convenient mechanism for acquiring the thread's return value (other than some fairly complex sub-classing).

The simplest way to handle this is to pass a placeholder - e.g., a list

Something like this:

```
from threading import Thread

expects = [5, 10]

def f(number: int, expects: list, result: list):
    result.append(number in expects)

for v in 3, 5:
    result = []
    monitor_thread = Thread(target=f, args=(v, expects, result))
    monitor_thread.start()
    monitor_thread.join()
    print(*result)
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```

**Alternative:**

The concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor makes this easier. For example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

expects = [5, 10]

def f(expects: list, number: int):
    return number in expects

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for r in executor.map(partial(f, expects), [3, 5]):
        print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```